# Step up converter 1-3V to 5V fixed for supercapacitor

Tags: converter, supercapacitor

I would like to use this step up converter, [LT1073 - Micropower
DC/DC Converter
Adjustable and Fixed 5V, 12V](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1073fa.pdf), to drive an input in the range of 1 V to 3 V (input is a supercapacitor).

In the datasheet there are examples of voltage inputs from 1.05 V to 1.55 V to get a fixed 5 V output. Could this IC work with an input range of 1.05 V to 3 V to get 5 V voltage at the output?

The capacitor I am using is 2.3V 50F, so if you have any suggestions how to use it at highest efficiency, please share your advices.

Comment: don't feed 3v to that cap, make sure 2.3 is the max or it might get exciting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First page of the datasheet, left hand side says "Operates at Supply Voltages from 1V to 30V".

Page two says "input voltage... step up mode... 1.0 (min) 12,6 (max)".

Page 6 says input  of 1.05V, output of 5.

So, the datasheet says in three places that it will work.

Comment: Thanks. So it will work for input range of 1V to 3V without changing external components and it will give an output 5V? I am asking this because datasheet page 6 table says, that inductor and capacitor values varies depending on input voltage. The current I need for output is 50mA at 5V.

Comment: The data sheet gives varying values to try and keep efficiency high. As you're operating over a wide range, efficiency will be compromised. (As will EMC performance, but that's not your problem at the moment)

Comment: @Tom you will not get 50 mA @ 5 volts. Look at the example on page 1. This requirement should have been stated in your question.

Comment: @Tom as Andy aka says, you are now putting in a new requirement for current. Page one of the datasheet says "5V at 40mA from
an input as low as 1.25V and 5V at 10mA from a 1V input".

Comment: Thanks for answers. Now I see that for 50mA at 5V requires at least 1.7V input, otherwise the output voltage will drop.